# Javascript while loop infinite loop

Tags: javascript, loops

I'm not all that experienced of a code and I'm stuck on a  the while loop towards the bottom of the block of code below

My code is supposed to get the date, check if today is a day when we don't ship (saturdays, sundays, holidays) and, if it is, add 1 day until until it finds the next day that we are on open on and write it to the document.

```
var target = new Date();
var targetDay = target.getDay();
var targetDate = target.getDate();
var targetMonth = target.getMonth();

function checkIfClosedOnTarget(targetDay,targetDate,targetMonth){
    var areOpenOnTarget = true;
    if(
         targetDay == 0 || 
         targetDay == 6  ||
         (targetDate == 1 && targetMonth == 0) || // New Year's Day
         (targetMonth == 4 && targetDate >= 25 &&  targetDay == 1) || // Memorial Day
         (targetMonth == 6 && targetDate == 4) || //Independence Day
         (targetMonth == 8 && targetDate <= 7 && targetDay == 1)|| //Labor Day
         (targetMonth == 10 && targetDate <= 28 && targetDate >= 22 && targetDay == 4)|| // Thanksgiving Day
         (targetMonth == 11 && targetDate == 25)
     ){
         areOpenOnTarget = false;
     }

    if(areOpenOnTarget){
        return true;
    }else{
       return false;
    }
};

function addDaysUntilNextOpenDay() {
     while(checkIfClosedOnTarget(targetDay,targetDate,targetMonth) == false){
     target.setDate(target.getDate() + 1);
     }
 };
addDaysUntilNextOpenDay();

document.write("<p>Next shipment will ship out on " + target.getMonth() + " " +   target.getDate + ", " + target.getYear) + " at 4:00pm Pacific Standard Time ";
```

Comment: you should only return the logical sentence in the ''if'' statement of your ''checkIfClosedOnTarget'' function. The rest of code is redundant.

Comment: I think you could do a lot to clean up your code.  For example, you have a method called `checkIfClosedOnTarget` which would imply that it returns `true` if closed, but it returns true if open.  And it's wordy.  Try renaming it to `isOpen` or `isOpenOn`.  Then you really just need to return false in your big if statement, and true outside of it.  There is no need for the `areOpenOnTarget` variable at all.

Comment: fyi, this isn't recursion....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with this line `target.setDate(target.getDate() + 1);` you update the `target` but you never update the `targetDay`, `targetDate`, `targetMonth` variables... so the `checkIfClosedOnTarget()` function keeps getting passed the same values, resulting in the *infinite loop*.

So you might want to update them after you set the next day:

```
while(checkIfClosedOnTarget(targetDay,targetDate,targetMonth) === false){
     target.setDate(target.getDate() + 1);

     // update parameters
     targetDay = target.getDay();
     targetDate = target.getDate();
     targetMonth = target.getMonth();
}
```

Comment: +1, you've identified the problem.  However, I think it would be much, much cleaner to define `targetDay` et al as local variables in `checkIfClosedOnTarget` and just pass in `target` to that function.

Comment: @MarkPeters Agreed, there's different ways of passing the information in. Up to the OP to decide on how they want to best approach it.